# Best resolution for Tesseract-OCR

Tags: pdf, ocr, resolution, tesseract

What is the best tif image resolution for tesseract OCR ?
I just convert a OCR-PDF using ghostscript, resolution 1200 give better conversion to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300dpi is the value I frequently see in various Tesseract documentations ([FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/tess3/FAQ-Old.md#is-there-a-minimum--maximum-text-size-it-wont-read-screen-text), [Manual](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#rescaling)). Higher than that may or may not produce better results but it definitely increases the processing time due to the larger images.

Comment: I am using Ghostscript to convert OCR PDF to image is there any option for specify dpi more Than resolution

Comment: You can set the [Output resolution](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Output_resolution) using the -r switch.